# Show notification on card update Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, add-on

How do I make a notification appear on card load?

In the docs I found this: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/notification?hl=en

But I'm not sure how to use it correctly in my situation.

**Wanted result**

When the user clicks a button a card is updated via `CardService.newNavigation().updateCard(card)` and once the card is updated a notification is shown.

**edit**

The error shown happens when i try to return a card that fetches some data and the notification as an array `[card, notification]`. When I return only one of the above it works as expected.

The error is shown bellow.

```
The value returned from Apps Script has a type that cannot be used by the add-ons platform. Also make sure to call build on any builder before returning it. Value:values {
  proto_value {
    type_url: "type.googleapis.com/caribou.api.proto.addons.templates.publicapi.ContextualAddOnMarkup.Card"
    value: "\n\017\n\rVyber projekt\022\375\001\022\372\001B\367\001\n\020dropdown_project\020\003\032\017\n\aVyberte\020\001\032\002-1\032\023\n\005Await\020\000\032\b105966.0\032!\n\024\342\233\265\357\270\217 Freelo addons\020\000\032\a31512.0\032\031\n\vgmail addon\020\000\032\b104757.0\032\020\n\002ll\020\000\032\b105967.0\032\022\n\004test\020\000\032\b104596.0\032\023\n\005test2\020\000\032\b104741.0\032\022\n\004null\020\000\032\b105969.0\032\022\n\004null\020\000\032\b105968.0\"\021\n\rshowToDoLists \000*\aProjekt\022G\022+\")\n\'\n\021Vytvo\305\231it Projekt\022\022\022\020\n\016newProjectForm\022\030\"\026\n\024\n\006Logout\022\n\022\b\n\006logOut\"\fprojectsCard"
  }
}
values {
  proto_value {
    type_url: "type.googleapis.com/caribou.api.proto.addons.templates.publicapi.SubmitFormResponseMarkup"
    value: "\022\027\022\025Projekt byl vytvo\305\231en"
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. You are working on G Suite Add-on (not a G Suite Editor Add-on) , right? Please show what you tried.

Comment: Yes, I'm making a Gmail addon. I tried putting the update card and the notification action into an array and return both but it always resulted in an error.

Comment: Can you show you code resulting in error and specify which error it gives you?

Comment: I added an edit section to my post with closer info.

Comment: It would be useful to see your code.